# PHP Ajax form sending

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am posting form data to a PHP script using a jQuery serizalize function.

My script is running ok and the PHP is executing although I am not receiving the posted values from my form in my PHP.

Here is my code

**HTML:**

```
<form id="contact_form" action="process.php" method="POST">
                        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Ringo Starr" form="contact_form">
                        </div>
                        <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="john@beatles.com" form="contact_form">
                        </div>
                        <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="formMessageArea" name="message" placeholder="Your message here..." form="contact_form"></textarea>
                            <span class="countdown"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="result"></div>
                        <button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

**Ajax Post:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        datatype : 'html',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.status === "success") {
                $('.result').text("Success!!");
            } else if (response.status === "error") {
                $('.result').text("Error!!");
            }
        }
    });
```

**Serialized Data:**

```
name=Jamie+Berke&email=jamie_b25%40hotmail.com&message=testing+123
```

**Here is my PHP:**

```
<?php
$autoResponse = true; //if set to true auto response email will be sent, if you don't want autoresponse set it to false
$autoResponseSubject = "Demo Contact Form"; 
$autoResponseMessage = "Hi, thank you testing the JQuery Contact Form Demo.";
$autoResponseHeaders = "From: email_from@yourWebsite.com";  

//we need to get our variables first
$email_to =   'jamie_b25@hotmail.com';
$subject  =   'A enquiry for The Retros!';
$name     =   $_POST['name'];
$email    =   $_POST['email'];
$message  =   $_POST['message'];

$body = "From: $name \r\nMessage: \r\n$message";

$headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: test@test.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";


if(mail($email_to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
    if($autoResponse === true){
        mail($email, $autoResponseSubject, $autoResponseMessage, $autoResponseHeaders);
    }
    echo 'success'; 
}else{
    echo 'error';/
}
```

?>

Here are the errors my PHP is returning:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Users\Jberke\Documents\Projects\theRetros\src\process.php on line 10
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0010     235032   1. {main}() C:\Users\Jberke\Documents\Projects\theRetros\src\process.php:0
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\Users\Jberke\Documents\Projects\theRetros\src\process.php on line 11
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0010     235032   1. {main}() C:\Users\Jberke\Documents\Projects\theRetros\src\process.php:0
>
> Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\Users\Jberke\Documents\Projects\theRetros\src\process.php on line 12
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0010     235032   1. {main}() C:\Users\Jberke\Documents\Projects\theRetros\src\process.php:0

If i add a `if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { }` around the PHP block nothing is returned to the jQuery-ajax success function and my form doesn't return any result although the script seems to execute fine.

Comment: I can't test this but just as a possible direction... Have you using `var_dump` on the entire `$_POST` variable? That can give you insight as to how it is getting passed via AJAX or if it is getting passed.

Comment: where did you declare the data var? can you share that line of code?

Comment: var data = $('#contact_form').serialize();

Comment: Look in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools. Is the request constructed the way you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Jquery ajax settings option "datatype" has incorrect value for your task, because of you are sending form data. You need to remove it.

```
datatype : 'html'
```

Also you need to pass serialized form data into settings option "data" or if your variable data is valid you can also pass it too.

```
data: $('#contact_form').serialize()
// or
data: data
```

And you need to prevent sending form without ajax, by returning false.

```
$form.submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(), // or data: data
        success: function(response) {
            ...
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>
                $('#submitButton').click(function(){
                    var data = $('#contact_form').serialize(); 
                        $.ajax({
                        url: $('#contact_form').attr('action'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        datatype : 'html',
                        data: data,
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response.status === "success") {
                                $('.result').text("Success!!");
                            } else if (response.status === "error") {
                                $('.result').text("Error!!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

Try this

Comment: Try what? This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What was the cause of the problem? What did you change to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var name = $("[name='name']").val();
var email = $("[name='email']").val();
var message = $("[name='message']").val();

      $.post('process.php',{name: name, email: email, message: message}, function(response){
                if (response.status === "success") {
                   $('.result').text("Success!!");
                } else (response.status === "error") {
                   $('.result').text("Error!!");
                }
        });
```